Using SUMPRODUCT(link...INDEX(link...MATCH(link....))) but link doesn't work unless files are open. How to overcome? Can I write a macros?
Financial summary workbook linking all individual financial workbooks. I'm using SUMPRODUCT(link...INDEX(link...MATCH(link....))) to calculate each cells, but #REF! error on the summary workbook unless I open each individual workbooks. Is there a way to overcome the error?
I've tried using Xlookup but the same error happens. I believe all these functions are dynamic arrays and unless I write a macros to overcome, otherwise it's inevitable to open each individual workbooks. Can I get help writing a macros, please?

The quickest and simplest solution is probably going to be - write (or record) some code that opens each source workbook and closes them.

Consider using Power Query to combine data from multiple workbooks. Then you can transform your data in PQ, summarize with pivot tables, or write formulas referencing the combined data.

Screenshots/here (Book 1 - source data, Book 2 - calcs to reference Book 1) refer:

Book1: source data
Book2: calcs based upon references to Book 1


Soln 1

Do not wrap functions around source data in different workbook (Book 1)
First bring source data into Book 2 using '=' sign which allows data to remain valid when Book 1 closed
Then do sumproducts/index/vlookup etc. to heart's desire (wrapping around local data now in Book 2).
When Book 2 data values are updated and links refreshed, updated calcs will work correctly (regardless of whether Book 1 open/closed).


Illustration
Book 1 with calculations referencing itself that will be cut/paste into Book 2. Once 1 closed, 2 will no longer shown valid results (problem described by OP).
Using steps 1-4, you can see that the desired values still display despite book 1 being closed.

note: there is no need to create functions in Book 1 first and then cut/paste into Book 2 - omit this as you wish - personal perference/ease to demonstrate references and set the problem up this side

note: I have noticed that if using tables as source data, then it is safer to reference traditional way (cell references, without bullets/fixing) - using 'Table Names in formulas' (accessible through Tools/Options/Formulas) are not always preserved as desired, although this may be a quirk associate with OneDrive syncing. They work if columns comprise values that have not themselves been derived using a function within the table it seems...





notes: it is not necessary to set up any of the source/referenced data as tables

Alternative solutions 2-4:

Using Power Query to import the table/data/file(s) is more elegant and if you touch up on Power M functions (help file generally helpful, power queries are otherwise fairly intuitive / user-friendly)



Another way to referene the cells is to perform the calculations in the source of oirin (book 1 here), then take them across by referencing direclty - this options is less robust/flexible.
Wrapping a pivot table around the source (book 1) amounts to more or less the same thing (with the added effort of getting the correct format displaying for subsequent analysis.  Further, you have certain restrictions in terms of the graphs if using pivot chart feature (no combo charts, everytime you alter the graph the underlying structure of the pivot also changes - so plenty of space required each etc.
Finally, you could simply proceed as you have, close Book 1, and don't press update links. This is least favourable since every time you want to update calcs/include another one you must go 'edit/links/update/refresh values' and that't not always bullet proot br.


Closing remarks (some sense-checking with Chat-GPT4o proposals - contraversial - oooh)

Certain functions will work when other worbook closed: e.g  vlookup(local file to external data frame) - this is much the same kind of these associated herewith. Same comments apply with referencing table names or cells with calculation
Range names - same as proposal above - this is simply another way to import data of interest as before - create name in Book 1, whilst still open set cell/range in Book 2 = the name range from Book 1. This is probably neater than using direct cell reference as you can take advantage of dynamic functionality for different data table dimensions when specifiyng the named range in Book 1. I have tested to see if its sticky with Table name ranges although I think named ranges in excel automatically convert any table references to actual cell equivalent formats (you'd need to check if you get this far).
Interestingly, simple operators like D2+D3 can be used although the bot missed that one.
I tinkered a bit with the VB version of it's SQL method and think a new approach would be better without creating OLEB connections and what not
I also tried my luck with 'Python in Excel' (here), but couldn't find a neat / easy (any) way to reference the other workbook - despite me putting the correct location with / os.path.join and 'r' in front of stringified location addresses (for non-literal character interpretation the data in from another workook) - but this is way beyond the remit and so I gave up to move to another Q.

Hope this helps!
Peace
~~
